# Can 'find' or any other tool search for files breadth-first?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, find

Sometimes I know a file is not so deep away, but a very dense sub-directory does not allow me to find the files I want easily.

Can [find](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html) (or any other tool) look for files using breadth-first search?

Comment: And master the "prune" option of the **find** command while you are at it. No sense in getting mired in some depth-first recursive search of some deeply rooted, highly populated directory subtree when you know the object - file or directory - that you are looking for ain't there.

Comment: In case you're still looking for such a thing, I wrote [this](https://github.com/tavianator/bfs)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, sort of.

You can use the `-depth` option to make it process a directory's contents before the directory itself. You can also use the `-maxdepth` option to limit how many directories down it will drill.

Comment: "sort of" is right -- this still isn't a real breadth-first search, since a/b/c will be visited before a/d.  Good enough for most purposes, though.

Comment: That's still not breadth first search. That's just limited depth first search. Limited depth first search does solve the problem of finding "a file [that] is not so deep away", but nonetheless this is definitely not breadth first search.

Answer (score 10):

Horrible hack, won't work with `-0` or any actions other than `-print`, inefficient, etc. etc…

```
#!/bin/bash
i=0
while results=$(find -mindepth $i -maxdepth $i "$@") && [[ -n $results ]]; do
    echo "$results"
    ((i++))
done
```

Basically this just runs

```
find -mindepth 0 -maxdepth 0
find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1
find -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2
…………………………………………………………………………
```

until `find` returns non-zero status or prints nothing.

Comment: Looks like [iterative depth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_deepening_depth-first_search) to me...

Comment: @MattLuongo: From your link: "IDDFS is equivalent to breadth-first search, but uses much less memory;"

Comment: @MooingDuck I wasn't disagreeing that this works, just pointing out it has a specific name. IDFS is also slower than BFS, since it requires re-traversing the prior level on the tree each time. The argument I've heard is that in most search problems, that runtime cost is dominated by the cost of traversing `n+1`, so it's often worthwhile.

Comment: Note though that if you're doing any significant processing at each node, the difference between BFS and IDFS for a particular search space can be significant.

Comment: Minigolf: `for((i=0;1;i++));do find -mindepth $i -maxdepth $i|grep .||break;done`

Answer (score 6):

A breadth-first find using variable as its queue.

Create `bfs.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

queue="$1"
shift

while [ -n "$queue" ]
do
    echo "$queue" | xargs -I'{}' find {} -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 $*
    queue=`echo "$queue" | xargs -I'{}' find {} -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d`
done
```

Make it executable:

`$ chmod u+x ./bfs.sh`

Then you can do a breadth-first find by:

`$ ./bfs.sh /path/to/somewhere -name foobar`

Comment: great answer, will definitely use in my personal bin

Answer (score 4):

Use `find` with the `--maxdepth` option.

That is at the [Directories](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Directories) section in your reference page; might find other options more suitable depending on your needs.

To achieve exact breadth first searching, you will need to loop with mixed `--mindepth` and `--maxdepth` options. But, I don't think it is necessary to be that exact, a depth limited search will usually suffice.

Answer (score 0):

```
find . | awk '{FS = "/" ; print "", NF, $F}' | sort -n  | awk '{print $2}' | xargs grep -d skip "search term"
```

It uses find to list all the files.  The first awk command counts all the '/' characters.  It sorts on the count and then drops the count column.  Finally it uses xargs to grep the sorted list of files.

It is really ugly.