# Reading and Printing All Directories and Files in Java With Only Loops

Tags: java, file, directory, iteration

I am trying to read all the directory and files including the subdirectories. Each time it finds the files and directories, the program will print what's inside the folder. This will continue if it finds another directory and prints its contents as well. I'm having trouble getting the other directory data when there are multiple folders in a directory. My code only works when there is only one way to go. Here is my code. DirFolder3 should print its contents as well. This program shouldn't use recursion as well. The output should be like the DirFolder1, DirFolder2, and DirFolder4 directories. Thanks for your help.

**Main File:**

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class DirectoryRead {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        DirInfo scan = new DirInfo();
        
        scan.readDirectory();
    }
}
```

**Read Class:**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class DirInfo {
    
    String dirName = "";
    String childName = "";
    String fileName = "";
    
    public void readDirectory() throws IOException {
        //starting directory
        File dir = new File("C:\\DirFolder1");
        
        //if a directory (parent) exists, loop
        while (dir.exists()) {
            //print the parent/current directory name
            dirName = dir.getName();
            System.out.println(dirName);
            //list all files in current directory
            File [] files = dir.listFiles();
            
            //loop through array and see if a directory or file exists
            for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                //if there's a directory, print name
                if (files[i].isDirectory()) {
                    childName = files[i].getName();
                    System.out.println("\t" + childName);
                }
                //if there's a file, print name
                if (files[i].isFile()) {
                    fileName = files[i].getName();
                    System.out.println("\t" + fileName);
                }
            }
            //make child directory the new parent/current directory and repeat
            dir = new File(dir, childName);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
DirFolder1
    DirFolder2
    Sample File1.txt
DirFolder2
    DirFolder3
    DirFolder4
    Document2.txt
    Document3.txt
DirFolder4
    Dir4TextFile.txt
```

Comment: What output you are expecting? Add this to the question for clarity.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Traversing directories without using recursion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3932382/traversing-directories-without-using-recursion)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for traversing the directory with BFS. It is alternative to DFS which is using recursion.

With BFS you can use Queue or another data structure to keep track of the sub directories that you haven't traversed yet. Depends on what output you want to have (which order to traverse) you can decide in which order you are pasting and retrieving the elements from this DS.

You can check the implementation here https://www.techiedelight.com/traverse-given-directory-bfs-dfs-java/